# Why is pygame.surfarray.pixels_alpha throwing a ValueError?

Tags: python, pygame, alpha

I am trying to apply a numpy array of `uint8` alpha values (pickled array [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/6160029/g.pickle)) to a surface, but I keep getting a `ValueError:  unsupported colormasks for alpha reference array`.

```
s = pygame.Surface((100, 100))
s.fill((126, 126, 126))  # make it grey
pxa = pg.surfarray.pixels_alpha(s)
```

Here is the full traceback:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-81-8c19259f8aa5> in <module>()
----> 1 pxa = pg.surfarray.pixels_alpha(s)

/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pygame/surfarray.pyc in pixels_alpha(surface)
    206         return numericsf.pixels_alpha (surface)
    207     elif __arraytype == "numpy":
--> 208         return numpysf.pixels_alpha (surface)
    209     raise NotImplementedError("surface arrays are not supported")
    210 

/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pygame/_numpysurfarray.pyc in pixels_alpha(surface)
    295         start = 3
    296     else:
--> 297         raise ValueError("unsupported colormasks for alpha reference array")
    298 
    299     array = numpy.ndarray \

ValueError: unsupported colormasks for alpha reference array
```

The `pixels_alpha` docstring mentions that a 32-bit `Surface` with per-pixel alpha values are required.  I checked the surfaces bit size with `Surface.get_bitsize`, and confirmed that it returns `32`.  That being said, I have no idea how to check if it has per-pixel alpha values.  Might this be the problem?  If so, how do I check?  If not, what's am I missing?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should initialise with per-pixel alpha:

```
surface = pygame.Surface((100, 100), flags=pygame.SRCALPHA)
```

This does not require an initialised display.

---

**Old answer:**

You need it to have per-pixel alpha, which isn't automatic even for 32-bit images:

```
surface = pygame.Surface((100, 100)).convert_alpha()
```

And to use convert_alpha you need to have initialised the display:

```
pygame.display.set_mode((X, Y))
```

Comment: You again!  Works like a charm, thank you!  Do you happen to know what exactly this per-pixel alpha business is all about?

Comment: Not particularly. Not having per-pixel alpha allows much faster blits but I'm not really sure why 32 bits are used by default in that case. // Also note the updated answer.

Comment: Thanks for the update. That does simplify things a lot!  I have another (related) issue now, which I've posted in a seperate question.  If you have time, would you please take a look at it?  Thanks!  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19058022/why-is-surface-unlock-failing-to-unlock-the-surface-for-blitting