# Why is Surface.unlock failing to unlock the surface for blitting?

Tags: python, pygame

I'm trying to apply a numpy array of alpha values to a surface.  I'm able to do so, but the surface remains locked after this operation such that I cannot blit the surface to my display.

Below is a simple test case, using the alpha array, `g`, pickled [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/6160029/g.pickle).

```
import pygame as pg

pg.init()
screen = pg.display.set_mode((600, 600))

s = pg.Surface((100, 100)).convert_alpha()
s.fill((126, 126, 126))  # make it grey
pxa = pg.surfarray.pixels_alpha(s)  # reference the alpha values

pxa[::] = g  # g is the array of alpha values
del pxa  # shouldn't deleting the array be enough to unlock the surface?
s.unlock()  # explicitly unlock for good measure

s.get_locked()  # returns True
```

So what gives?  I tried blitting the surface to `screen` anyway, but (predictably) I get an error about `s` still being locked.

Advice would be most welcome!

Comment: I think you should try running that sample. It doesn't run and when you fix it so that it does the problem does not occur.

Comment: @Veedrac, Ha!  That's what I get for working from the interpreter.  I've corrected the code, but I'm still getting the same issue...

Comment: I run the new code and get no locks. You can try `s.get_locks()` to see what's locking it. Note that you should use `pg.Surface((100, 100), flags=pg.SRCALPHA)` from my updated answer to the last question to avoid needing to start the display (the display is quite distracting). // It might be that you're running in an environment that's preventing proper deletion; it always seemed dumb to me that `del` was required despite not actually having defined behaviour.

Comment: from the docs "The Surface this array references will remain locked for the lifetime of the array." http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surfarray.html#pygame.surfarray.pixels_alpha

Comment: @monkey, yes.  This is why I'm attempting to delete the pixel array.  However, it is very difficult to control object destruction in Python...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a sprite class and put the values in an update function. This way, the array will be created and destroyed within the scope of the function. Here's an example in which you can make the grey block transparent by pressing the space bar:

```py
import pygame
from pygame.locals import QUIT, KEYDOWN, K_ESCAPE, K_SPACE, SRCALPHA


class Game(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.init()
        self.width, self.height = 800, 800
        pygame.display.set_caption("Surfarray test")
        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((self.width, self.height))
        self.background = pygame.Surface((self.width, self.height))
        self.background.fill((255, 255, 255))
        self.background.convert()
        self.bar = pygame.Surface((200, 100))
        self.bar.fill((255, 0, 0))
        self.bar.convert()

        self.sprite = pygame.sprite.GroupSingle()
        self.sprite.add(CustomSprite(pygame.Rect(5, 5, 100, 100)))

    def input(self):
        for event in pygame.event.get():

            if event.type == QUIT:
                return False

            if event.type == KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == K_ESCAPE:
                    return False
                if event.key == K_SPACE:
                    # make bar transparent by pressing the space bar
                    self.sprite.update()

    def main(self):
        while True:
            if self.input() is False:
                return False
            self.draw()

    def draw(self):
        self.screen.blit(self.background, (0, 0))
        self.screen.blit(self.bar, (5, 5))
        self.sprite.draw(self.screen)
        pygame.display.update()


class CustomSprite(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, rect):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.rect = rect
        # SRCALPHA flag makes the pixel format include per-pixel alpha data
        self.image = pygame.Surface((rect.width, rect.height), SRCALPHA)
        self.image.convert_alpha()
        self.image.fill((126, 126, 126))

    # magic happens here
    def update(self):
        pxa = pygame.surfarray.pixels_alpha(self.image)
        pxa[:] = 100  # make all pixels transparent

if __name__ == "__main__":
    game = Game()
    game.main()
```

Comment: That's a very good idea, especially considering that I was planning on making a sprite class anyway.  I'll give that a shot and accept once I get it working.  Thanks a bunch!